# oculus mobile sdk (for Gear VR) with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, oculus, gear-vr

Has anyone got the Oculus native sdk (for Gear VR) working with Android Studio?

I am trying to get any of the included native samples working. It seems that you need to use the gradle experimental plugin (i.e. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0') with gradle version 2.10 to use the ndk with Android Studio now, and Eclipse ADT is no longer supported. But the samples use non-experimental gradle 1.5.
Am I correct in assuming the samples need to be migrated to use the experimental gradle plugin before you can build them? [I found this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Migrating-from-Traditional-Android-Gradle-Plugin) for migrating to the experimental plugin.

It works for simple gradle scripts, but there's no examples on the guide for migrating more complex gradle files. Has anyone successfully done this?
Or am I completely missing something here? Will this still work with Eclipse ADT (if I can find it)?